# Can I ask about identifying a sci-fi puzzle book?

Tags: discussion, scope, story-identification

I was thinking of posting a "story identification" question regarding a series I use to read as a child. I do not think any book continued from the other, but there was a constant theme of a space explorer of some sort crash landing on an alien planet.

The thing is, there was very little in regards to story. They were puzzle books. I can remember enough about the series to post an on-topic identification question (in theory) - but I was wondering how everyone would feel, given the fact that these books were primarily puzzle books, and not written literature.

I use to read these books as a child, and I would greatly appreciate being able to find them again. If such a question *would* be off-topic, how could I tailor it to *be* on-topic?

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. I'd say that science fiction can take many forms, and doesn't always look like a story; puzzle books about astronauts and aliens are just as much sci-fi as novels about astronauts and aliens. And we have in the past [accepted](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7343/31394) story-ID questions which turned out to be commercials.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As long as there was a consistent science fiction theme throughout, these books would be perfectly well on topic.

We've had other questions about [puzzle books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47639/sci-fi-quest-adventure-book-where-progress-was-determined-through-clues-keys-in) (typically of the CYOA variety) as well as scifi [artbooks](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49053/books-describing-different-kinds-of-spaceships) and the community seems broadly happy with them.