# Are story identification questions with no story on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, story-identification

On a post I recently put a bounty on, a user said:

> This might be a better question on the Arqade Stack Exchange -- they do video game identifications.

I said:

> [They don’t accept them](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12398/102999)

Then, the user (while still being wrong that it'd be on-topic there<sup>1</sup>) brought up an interesting question (emphasis mine):

> @Stormblessed It's not so much that Arqade "doesn't accept" game ID questions, and more a matter of SFF accepting story ID questions which are part of a game. **But what's being asked about here is all game -- there's no story elements in the question.**

This question is, really, all game. **Is it still on-topic even though it's looking for the work based on details about the mechanics and art of a game apparently without any sort of plot whatsoever?**

<sup>1</sup><sub>No offense to the user, sorry if I sound annoying.</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I ask about identifying a sci-fi puzzle book?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10859/can-i-ask-about-identifying-a-sci-fi-puzzle-book) - there's mention of works without actual stories in that; for instance, an artbook that only depicted spaceships. Copied: _"

As long as there was a consistent science fiction theme throughout, these books would be perfectly well on topic."_

Comment: The short answer is that the work here was on-topic, but the question wasn't.